# Power BI how can I display multiple measures in a table like view

Tags: powerbi

I have created multiple measures in my report, is it possible I can display in separate visuals grouping these measures in a table like manner?  i.e. separate visuals for fruit and meat

Also, to be able to drill through to see the details that make up the value of the measures.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use [multi-row card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-types-for-reports-and-q-and-a#cards) visual:

[image]